# Data initialization and watchers using P5Js and VueJs

Tags: vuejs2, p5.js

As I am trying to play with evolutionary algorithms and building visualization tools of the process, I'd like to use VueJs with P5Js.
I have this code: [(SO) Playing with Evolutionary Algorithms on Codepen.io](http://codepen.io/hsolatges/pen/VbyBdM)

The problem is that Vue instance's data `population` does not update properly.

Here what I tried to do:

- Pass the global objet `Game` as Vue instance's data. Then `population` get updated properly, but the data is so big that everything get laggy;
- Populate `Game.population` array when declared, but it does not work: P5JS throw me an error `createVector() is not defined`;
- Populate `Game.population` array in Vue instance's `beforeCreate()` method. It does not work neither. Giving me an other error;
- Proxy `Game.population` by an other object `Data` declared globally or in Vue instance's `beforeCreate()` method, for curating interesting cells data (I don't need the `pos` attribute) and so avoiding `createVector()` error. It is a dead end;
- Thinking about hoisting, I wondered if VueJS was initialized before P5JS run. It is the case. But I can't figure how to change that.

What is the issue here? How should I refactor my script so Vue instance's data and Game.population can be linked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution isn't as pretty as throwing your `Game` object into the Vue instance, but it works.

**Forked here:** https://codepen.io/andymerskin/pen/LyoEmW

Here's what I changed:

1. Added a [computed getter/setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) for `population`, giving you a clean way to render the array's length in the template, and the ability to assign it in your Game loop using `app.population = Game.population` in your `Game.doPopulatePacks` routine.
2. Changed `data.property` in the Vue instance to `_property` to keep the naming conventions paired up for use inside the computed property. It does come with the caveat that it's [no longer proxied to avoid conflicts with Vue's internal properties](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#data), since we're leaning on the computed property in the template.
   (Currently, there isn't a clear convention for defining private properties in a Vue instance, even though underscores `_` are the preference in JS more broadly.)

And with that, you'll see in the forked demo that your game's population stays up to date in the UI.

Comment: Wow. That is both very nice of you and very awesome answer. Thanks for pointing out Vue computed setters / getters. I need to dive into it. Thanks again!